# Backbone Router confusion on howto trigger

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I can't seem to get the Backbone Router working in an expected manner. I i) instantiate my Router, then ii) call Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true, root: '/' } ). With the code below...

- 1) going to "/dashboard" or "/grid", the defined functions are not called
- 2) when I invoke myrouter.navigate("grid"), the defined functions are not called
- **) However, if I then go back or forwards throught the history, then the defined functions are called.

```
    Router : Backbone.Router.extend

        routes:
          "dashboard":                  "dashboard"
          "grid/:storyid":              "grid"

        dashboard: ->
          console.log("...")

        grid: (storyid) ->
          console.log("...")
```

What do I need to do to get cases 1) and 2) to work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you create an instance of the router and start the history tracking? IE this bit: `Backbone.history.start()`

Comment: Yes. `myrouter = new router.Router()`, then `Backbone.history.start( { pushState: true, root: '/' } )`.

Comment: Can you try putting a / in front of the "dashboard" route so it would read: "/dashboard":                  "dashboard"

Comment: Try `myrouter.navigate('grid', {trigger: true})`. [router doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router is working exactly as it's supposed to. I think your expectations of how it works, and why, are off.

> 1) going to "/dashboard" or "/grid", the defined functions are not called

When you type "/dashboard" or "/grid" in to your browser's URL bar, your browser makes a request to your server to get that url. This bypasses the router because the browser is making the request back to the server.

The only time typing a URL in to the browser's URL input would not request a new page from the server, is when you are only modifying the hash fragment: "#whatever".

> when I invoke myrouter.navigate("grid"), the defined functions are not called

The default behavior of `router.navigate` is to update the URL w/ the appropriate route, but not that route to be handled by the router - exactly what you are describing.

If you want to force the browser to process the route change, pass `true` as a second argument: `myrouter.navigate("grid", true)`

> **) However, if I then go back or forwards throught the history, then the defined functions are called.

This works because the router has registered itself w/ the browsers history API and is given the opportunity to handle the URL changes that are caused by the fwd / back buttons, before the browser goes back to the server to get the requested URL.

Comment: I eventually solved this by creating a `navi` function wrapper on *myobj*. That wrapper just calls `this.navigate("asdf", { trigger: true })`, which gives me the expected behaviour. I still find this frustrating, however, because directly calling `myobj.navigate("asdf", { trigger: true })` left me this problem I'm reporting here. But the solution you gives also works. I'm confused as to why A) `myobj.navigate("asdf", true)` works, but B) `myobj.navigate("asdf", { trigger: true })` does not. And why does wrapping the call in B), suddenly make that call work. I find it very wonky.